# Render object with offset in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, render

During learning libGDX I encountered a problem with rendering mountains on background. In book I have folowing part of code:

```
private void init () {
 dimension.set(10, 2);
 regMountainLeft = 
Assets.instance.levelDecoration.mountainLeft;
 regMountainRight = 
Assets.instance.levelDecoration.mountainRight;
 // shift mountain and extend length
 origin.x = -dimension.x * 2;
 length += dimension.x * 2;
 }
```

In this part we shift origin on the opposite side of y axis to render first texture at this starting point according to hide offset between different textures of mountains (here will be three batch of texture layers).

```
private void drawMountain (SpriteBatch batch, float offsetX, 
float offsetY, float tintColor) {
TextureRegion reg = null;
batch.setColor(tintColor, tintColor, tintColor, 1);
float xRel = dimension.x * offsetX;
float yRel = dimension.y * offsetY;
// mountains span the whole level
int mountainLength = 0;
mountainLength += MathUtils.ceil(length / (2 * dimension.x));
mountainLength += MathUtils.ceil(0.5f + offsetX);
for (int i = 0; i < mountainLength; i++) {
// mountain left
reg = regMountainLeft;
batch.draw(reg.getTexture(), origin.x + xRel, position.y + 
origin.y + yRel, origin.x, origin.y, dimension.x, dimension.y, 
scale.x, scale.y, rotation, reg.getRegionX(), reg.getRegionY(), 
reg.getRegionWidth(), reg.getRegionHeight(), false, false);
xRel += dimension.x;
// mountain right ...
```

Here we define how much full textures will be drawn with `mountainLength += MathUtils.ceil(length / (2 * dimension.x));` and `mountainLength += MathUtils.ceil(0.5f + offsetX);`. In this part I catch a problem with understanding the logic. Why do we use exactly `0.5f` in `mountainLength += MathUtils.ceil(0.5f + offsetX);` and also what is the logic of this line.
For example if we have negative offset, we move our texture to the left, so here will be gap in the end of full texture batch, so we need to close it therefore we need to increase `mountainLength`, it will be possible if we change `mountainLength += MathUtils.ceil(0.5f + offsetX);` to `mountainLength += MathUtils.ceil(0.5f - offsetX);`.
Help me to undersand this part of code maybe I am missing something.
Also attach render part:

```
public void render (SpriteBatch batch) {
 // distant mountains (dark gray)
 drawMountain(batch, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
 // distant mountains (gray)
 drawMountain(batch, 0.25f, 0.25f, 0.7f);
 // distant mountains (light gray)
 drawMountain(batch, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.9f);
 }
```